# How to specify text color in React using Material Design

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design

My question is actually simple, but after looking at the Material Design documentation, I didn't quite understand how you can specify the color for the text.

I have a component called "Introduction" I want to apply some kind of Typography color

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: 500,
    },
});

export default function Introduction() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>Welcome to JavaScript</Typography>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I understand that this approach can be applied.

```
<Typography style={{color: "red"}} variant="h5" gutterBottom>JavaScript</Typography>
```

Or specify className, but I want to know how any color can be specified using Material Design

Also I tried to use thickness for the text but it doesn't work

```
<Typography fontWeight={900} variant="h5" gutterBottom>JavaScript</Typography>
```

Comment: What do you mean by any color can be specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using latest @material-ui/core, base on the documentation you need to enclose the text into a Box tag and set the fonWeight on it

```
<Typography style={{ color: "red" }} variant="h5" gutterBottom>
    <Box fontWeight={900}>JavaScript</Box>
</Typography>
```